# Couldn't access a sprite group's x and y position in pygame

Tags: pygame

I've been struggling about this for some time now, I wanted to make a restart state for my game, where the player's position starts back at the starting position, but I can't seem to find a way to do the same for my enemy sprites that are in a group

here's the code for my enemy group:

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
left_enemy = pygame.sprite.Group()
right_enemy = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(8):
    enemies = Enemy(-100, random.randrange(screen_height- 30))
    all_sprites.add(left_enemy)
    left_enemy.add(enemies)

for i in range(8):
    enemy_r = EnemyRight(screen_width + 45, random.randrange(screen_height- 30))
    all_sprites.add(right_enemy)
    right_enemy.add(enemy_r)
```

is there any way for me to access the x and y values of these sprites that are in the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pygame.sprite.Sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects (should) have `.rect` attributes. You can iterate through the items in the [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and get the position of each item:

```py
for enemy in right_enemy:
    x = enemy.rect.x
    y = enemy.rect.y
    print(x, y)
```

Alternatively you can get a lit of the *Sprites* in the *Group* with  [`pygame.sprite.Group.sprites`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.sprites):

```py
if len(right_enemy) > 0:
    first_enemy = right_enemy.sprites()[0]
    x = first_enemy.rect.x
    y = first_enemy.rect.y
    print(x, y)
```